# Why Blockchain declined my API key

Tags: php, blockchain

I want to integrate blockchain API in PHP to send and receive bitcoins in my website  and I have account in blockchain .I gone through [this](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api) and I requested a blockchain API Key using this link https://api.blockchain.info/v2/apikey/request/ .

After this I got email that my "**API key is declined**". Before requesting a API key I accepted terms of service but I don't know why blockchain declined my API key .And I resubmitted same form but i am getting message as "A request for this URL is already pending".

So, please suggest me how can I create API key in blockchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request API key using your domain email id. If you have domain called www.abcd.com then create a email id your domain (Example : somename@abcd.com.) and request API key. I think this will help you.